# HTML form filled with post parameter string. String getting truncated

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form (form2) with variable called cat:

```
<input type="text" name="cat" value=<?php echo $_POST['cat']; ?>><br> <b>
```

File A ---> File B

File A gets input from form1 and posts to File B, which has a form called form2.

This form gets the POST variables from form1, and uses them, but also takes in some additional input. Cat, which I can see bc it's input type is text is truncated for some reason. Even though cat is normally only 1400 characters, it is truncated down to 164 for some reason.
Why/How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose *value's* value in quotes, as such:

```
value=<?php echo $_POST['cat']; ?>
```

to

```
value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['cat']); ?>"
```

Comment: It depends on what your $_POST['cat'] contains. Also, if this were a real program, I'd highly suggest you apply htmlentities() function to your $_POST['cat'] variable to avoid security issues.

Comment: but my cat contains a json string. before i added the double quotes, i got a shorter string, but not i get just a "{"

Comment: Post has been updated to include htmlentities. That should escape the quotes in your JSON. If you try to do a "view source" on your browser it would show it more clearly.

Comment: I used htmlspecialchars and it worked...idk why da heck u can get the { though